# Time Complexity Clarification on Algorithm

Tags: ruby, algorithm, time-complexity

Note: I've asked another question on this algorithm before, but this one is clarifying a time complexity question.

Working on the following algorithm:

> Given an array of non-negative integers, you are initially positioned
>   at the first index of the array.
>
> Each element in the array represents your maximum jump length at that
>   position.
>
> Determine if you are able to reach the last index.
>
> For example:
>
> - `A = [2,3,1,1,4]`, return `true`.
> - `A = [3,2,1,0,4]`, return `false`.

Below was my initial, brute force (with memoization) solution before I optimized according to my previous SO post [Speeding up solution to algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42424607/speeding-up-solution-to-algorithm)

On that question, I had a discussion with a fellow user regarding the time complexity of my initial algorithm and I just wanted to make sure that I'm understanding correctly. The code below is an O(N) time algorithm correct? My code times out for big test inputs, so I'm assuming it's a really slow O(N)... but still  O(N) and not O(N^2) correct? Because the memoization saves away jumpable? for each index if I'm not mistaken..

```
@memo = {}
def can_jump(nums)
    @memo = {}
    jumpable?(nums, 0) #new approach. launch a function for each index, memoize to get O(N) time. should be the same shit.
end
def jumpable?(nums, curr_idx)
    return true if curr_idx >= nums.length - 1 || nums.length == 1
    i = curr_idx
    true_counter = 0
    curr_val = nums[i]
    curr_val.downto(1) do |num|
        @memo[curr_idx + num] ||= jumpable?(nums, curr_idx + num )
        true_counter +=1 if @memo[curr_idx + num]
    end 
    true_counter > 0 
end
```

Comment: Since this code works, there's no specific problem, it might be better asked on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) or the [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: I'm afraid it wont work for `can_jump [0]` This `curr_idx >= nums.length - 1` will be true all the time if we have one length array, so `nums.length == 1` will never run. What about zero length input?

Comment: I gave you an example the first time around that demonstrated O(N^2). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42424607/speeding-up-solution-to-algorithm#comment71999938_42425057

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm runs in `O(n^2)`, not `O(n)`.

I'll demonstrate this with an example. Say your input is the following n-length array:

```
[n-2, n-3, n-4, ..., 2, 1, 0, 0]
```

That is, the `i`th element of the array equals `n-2-i` (except for the last element whose value is arbitrary as it doesn't have an influence on the result). Clearly, the algorithm is going to return `false` for the above input. Sadly, the amount of work we're going to do when being fed with the above input array is `O(n^2)`.

We start at position `0` and see that we can jump at most `n-2` steps. Then:

- we try jumping to position `n-1` and see we can't jump anywhere from there.
- we try jumping to position `n-2` and see we can jump to the following positions:

  - `n-1`
- we try jumping to position `n-3` and see we can jump to the following positions:

  - `n-1`
  - `n-2`
- we try jumping to position `n-4` and see we can jump to the following positions:

  - `n-1`
  - `n-2`
  - `n-3`
- ...
- we try jumping to position `1` and see we can jump to the following positions:

  - `n-1`
  - `n-2`
  - ...
  - `2`

Observe that the sub-bullets of each bullet represent positions to which we'll have to try jumping (we're going to find out each of them is a dead end, but we'll still try jumping there). Therefore, the total number of times we try checking whether we can jump to a particular position is:

```
0 + 1 + 2 + ... + (n-2) = (n-1)(n-2)/2 = O(n^2)
```

Hence, the reason your algorithm is not as fast as you would have expected is because it isn't linear but quadratic.